# Blazor pages with same variable on different pages causes ambiguous routes (upon rebuild)

Tags: c#, routes, blazor, url-routing, blazor-server-side

EDIT: For some reason, whenever I rebuild the application ALL of my changes to BO.razor are GONE. I created BO.razor by Saving As from BOType.razor, but I try to close BO.razor and reopen it and my changes are kept. The changes are there the first time. Rebuilding and BO.razor gets BOType.razor's content copied to it.

This obviously explains why the routes are conflicting but raises further, more troubling questions.

WTF.

---

I am trying to build my first Blazor application. The basic idea so far is that you can have different Business Objects with the pages being generated dynamically based on the Business Object Type.

So far I have two pages I'm trying to build

/{BOType}/  - List all valid BOs of this type

/{BOType}/{BOID:int}/ - Display this BO and its related data.

When I first ran the application, it worked exactly as I am imagining. /Form/ shows all saved forms, /Form/1 shows a page with Form 1's data.

When I rebuild the application, or save something while running the application with watch, I get the following exception:

```
InvalidOperationException: The following routes are ambiguous:
'{BOTName}' in 'BlazorApp.Pages.BOType'
'{BOTName}' in 'BlazorApp.Pages.BO'
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.LegacyRouteMatching.LegacyRouteTableFactory.RouteComparison(LegacyRouteEntry x, LegacyRouteEntry y)

InvalidOperationException: Failed to compare two elements in the array.
System.Collections.Generic.ArraySortHelper<T>.Sort(Span<T> keys, Comparison<T> comparer)
```

The same thing happens if I change the name of the variable (one named BOTName, one named BOType) or if I change the order around (/BOType/ and /view/BOType/BOID, or /BOType/ and /BOType/view/BOID).

The *infuriating* part is that whenever I try one of these changes it appears to work, because for some reason, the first time it interprets these paths it gets what I mean. Then I change something else and save or just rebuild and I get the ambiguous routes exception.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can somehow get my original working routes to stick, or some hints to the compiler to interpret it this way? I'm new to web application development so I'm still learning, Blazor's implementation seemed straightforward but apparently is unreliable :(

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that Blazor depends on compiler extensions, that the IDE is unaware of (actually it's aware, but imperfectly). Handling `razor` files mechanically (copying or moving) or rebuilding project may break Blazor's cache.

Sometimes cache is not persistent, so restarting Visual Studio (or whatever IDE are you using) may be enough. In other cases, you have to reset intermediate files as follows:

1. Quit the IDE.
2. Open the project directory and delete the output directories (`bin` and `obj`).
3. Reopen and rebuild the project.

If it did not help, and to avoid the same issue in the future:

- Never handle `razor` files like normal files, so no copying and no moving,
- If you want to copy a `razor` page/component, instead create a new one and copy code over. Moving is like copying, but old file gets deleted.

  - Be careful to give a different name to the copied type.
- Renaming is painful. Just do a reset (as described previously) after renaming normally.

Comment: To add to this, I use Visual Studio 2019, and do all my copying and renaming in FileExplorer outside VS.  VS then picks up the changes and fixes things without a re-start.